# MYSQL execution time shows less time as it actually needs to display the data

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a query in MYSQL as follows. It is to retrieve data to a Codeigniter program with populate a select box.

```
SELECT
    pharmacy_products.id,
    pharmacy_products.product_name,
    pharmacy_products.product_display_name,
    pharmacy_products.pack_size,
    pharmacy_products.top_up_level,
    pharmacy_products.current_physical_stock,
    pharmacy_products.purchasing_status,
    pharmacy_products.po_number,
    pharmacy_products.added_supplier,
    users.user_name,
    pharmacy_products.added_to_supplier_time,
    pharmacy_products.added_packs,
    pharmacy_products.last_pack_purchase_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        '',
        pharmacy_suppliers.suppier_alternate_name,
        '' SEPARATOR ''
    ) AS suppliers
FROM
    pharmacy_products
LEFT JOIN pharmacy_product_to_companies ON pharmacy_products.id = pharmacy_product_to_companies.product_id
LEFT JOIN pharmacy_suppliers ON pharmacy_product_to_companies.company_id = pharmacy_suppliers.id
LEFT JOIN users ON pharmacy_products.added_to_supplier_by = users.user_id
WHERE
    pharmacy_products.current_physical_stock <= pharmacy_products.re_order_level AND pharmacy_products.active_status = 1 AND pharmacy_products.approval_status = 1
GROUP BY
    pharmacy_products.id
```

At phpmyadmin it says like this

Showing rows 0 - 24 (2877 total, Query took 1.7426 seconds.)

But it took about 5 seconds to display data (in phpmyadmin). And this affects to the program also.

How can I solve this?

Comment: There doesn't look to be anything to solve that is related to MySQL. The query actually took that time, it's the code that's executing and displaying the data that is the problem, as the code always introduces extra processing time, how much depends on the code.

Comment: @AlexScott can you please explain it more? What is the relationship between 1.7 seconds and result generating time?

Comment: phpAdmin has a *Format* button, which you can use to format your query into something readable. Without knowing your database structure, it's impossible to help directly, but creating indexes on the joined table's main columns will help. Also changing the sequence of the joins might help.

Comment: @Vickel. Thank you for your help. Can you please explain me the reason for "Query took 1.7426 seconds" Vs data displayed after 5 seconds?

Comment: query time is one thing, loading all the bootstrap files (js, css, img, etc.) is another. I suppose the 5 seconds is the result f this. Anyway, once again, not knowing your datastructure, like the number of records in each table, the indexes, the type of each column, etc. makes it impossible to answer further in detail (at least to me). Anyway a 1.7second query is pretty slow, in case the number of records is not in the millions.

Comment: What @vickel said, your server/UI code adds processing time on top of the MySQL query time, as the query time is literally what it takes for the MySQL server to fetch the data, not the time it takes for the MySQL server plus your server code plus the code to render the data PLUS ANY BROWSER PLUGINS that are loading with your page, etc.